# os not supported error while building hotspot

Tags: linux, java

I am trying to build openjdk from source and I am using "HOTSPOT_RELEASE_VERSION=20.0-b12" on openjdk6 on ubuntu 12.04.
It prompts:

```
This OS is not supported:" `uname -a`; exit 1;<br>
This OS is not supported: Linux joker-Inspiron-1545 3.2.0-35-generic-pae #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 18:04:39 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux.
```

Can someone guide me on this please ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/925323

Answer (score 16, accepted):

change hotspot/make/linux/Makefile
SUPPORTED_OS_VERSION = 2.4% 2.5% 2.6% 2.7% **3%**

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'm finding the build system to be quite pathetic personally, and very frustrating to work with.

Comment: Thx for this since Linux Kernel 4.x and 5.x is there we need: SUPPORTED_OS_VERSION = 2.4% 2.5% 2.6% 3% 4% 5%

Answer (score 8):

An easier way than editing a file is to set the environment variable

`DISABLE_HOTSPOT_OS_VERSION_CHECK=ok`

Comment: For who ended up here because the icedtea6-native recipe was failing in Yocto: `EXTRA_OEMAKE += "DISABLE_HOTSPOT_OS_VERSION_CHECK=ok" `